# How to speed up FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

How can I speed up my `FindRoot` time, for the below code? It takes 25 seconds on my machine to find one single root for a set of $g$, $mx$, $m\psi$ values, I need to take around $10^5$ such points; I am stuck. Can I reduce the timing? And the function `sigv` is a numerical integration here.

```
xff[g_, mx_, mψ_?NumericQ] := Re[x /. FindRoot[
  x - Log[(0.038*2*1.22*10^19*mψ*sigv[x, g, mx, mψ])/Sqrt[107*x]],
    {x, 100}]]
```

**Where `sigv[x,g,mx,$m\psi$]`
is **

```
sigv[x_, g_, mx_, m\[Psi]_?NumericQ] = x/(8 m\[Psi]^5*BesselK[2, x]*
BesselK[2, x]) (NIntegrate[
 sig[x, g, mx, m\[Psi]]*s^(1/2)*BesselK[1, s^(1/2)*x/m\[Psi]], {s,
   4 m\[Psi]^2, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 20]);
```

And `sig[x,g,mx,$m\psi$]`

```
sig[x,g,mx,m\[Psi]] = 1/(2 + 4 Sqrt[2] E^-x)^4 16 (1 + 25.0038 E^(-2 x) + 
 3.98149 E^-x)^2 ((Sqrt[(1 - 
       0.00002116/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.459003 g^4 (0.00001058 + s) (-4 m\[Psi]^2 + 
        s)))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 + 
        s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       0.00009216/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.293596 g^4 (0.00004608 + s) (-4 m\[Psi]^2 + 
        s)))/(2 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 + 
        s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       0.0361/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.293596 g^4 (0.01805 + s) (-4 m\[Psi]^2 + 
        s)))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 + 
        s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       6.5025/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.459003 g^4 (3.25125 + s) (-4 m\[Psi]^2 + 
        s)))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 + 
        s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       120007./s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.459003 g^4 (60003.4 + s) (-4 m\[Psi]^2 + 
        s)))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 + 
        s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       1.04448*10^-6/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.293596 g^4 ((-1.04448*10^-6 + s) s + 

        4 m\[Psi]^2 (-s + 
           2.61121*10^-7 (7 - (6 s)/mx^2 + (3 s^2)/
               mx^4)))))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 +
         s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       0.04469/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.293596 g^4 ((-0.04469 + s) s + 
        4 m\[Psi]^2 (-s + 
           0.0111725 (7 - (6 s)/mx^2 + (3 s^2)/
               mx^4)))))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 +
         s)^2)) + (Sqrt[(1 - 
       12.6309/s)/(1 - (4 m\[Psi]^2)/s)] (0. + 
     0.293596 g^4 ((-12.6309 + s) s + 
        4 m\[Psi]^2 (-s + 
           3.15773 (7 - (6 s)/mx^2 + (3 s^2)/
               mx^4)))))/(4 \[Pi] s (0.0334177 g^4 mx^4 + (-mx^2 +
         s)^2)))
```

Comment: I don't think we can recommend anything unless you show us what `sigv` is, as the bottleneck is probably there.

Comment: If your 10^5 points are close to one another, you could use the preceding solution as a starting point for FindRoot. Another possible problem: you call NIntegrate with options AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal of 20, though the integrand involves hardware floating-point numbers: that precision can't be achieved. You might also try different integration methods.

Comment: Can you give an example of typical `g, mx, mψ` values?

Comment: g varies from 0.01 to 0.75, mx from 1000 to 5000 and $m\psi$ 800-2500. Although the solution will depend on the step size given for these ranges.

Comment: I don't see your definition of the function `sig[x_,g_,mx_,m\[Psi]_] := ...` You only have an expression `sig = ...` and yet you also have `NIntegrate[sig[x, g, mx, m\[Psi]] ...` Please explain.

Comment: Dear Somos plz check know, if u can help me out now..

Comment: Please verify that the code in the question runs without error by copying it into a fresh notebook, executing it, and then running `xff` with typical numerical values for its three arguments.  If not, please edit your question accordingly.